# Find maximum count for multi-index pandas series

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas series generated by a groupby that looks like this:

```
CustomerID  InvoiceDate        
12346.0     2011-01-18 10:01:00     1
12347.0     2011-10-31 12:25:00    47
            2010-12-07 14:57:00    31
            2011-01-26 14:30:00    29
            2011-04-07 10:43:00    24
                                   ..
18283.0     2011-07-14 13:20:00     1
            2011-11-10 15:07:00     1
18287.0     2011-10-12 10:23:00    38
            2011-05-22 10:39:00    29
            2011-10-28 09:29:00     3
```

I want to find out which CustomerID has the most number of unique InvoiceDates.

I have tried performing groupby with `value_counts()` and `size()` but neither of them are giving me the desired output. I would like the output format to be like this:

```
CustomerID  UniqueInvoiceDates        
12346.0     1
12347.0     4
...
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Try `df.groupby(level=0)['InvoiceDate'].nunique()`, or if you are sure that there are never duplicated invoice dates, just `df.groupby(level=0).size()`

Comment: you say this is generated by a groupby - you can set `as_index=False` in the groupby to preserve customerID and InvoiceDate as columns, then do a `groupby('CustomerID')['InvoiceDate'].nunique()` to get the number of dates on which you have an invoice.

Comment: Looks like `CustomerID` and `InvoiceDate` are indexes. You can just do `df.groupby(level=0).size().idxmax()`.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler your first solution worked great! Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CustomerID` is the index:

```
df.groupby(level=0)['InvoiceDate'].nunique()
CustomerID
12346.0    1
12347.0    4
18283.0    2
18287.0    3
Name: InvoiceDate, dtype: int64
```